# I have a little trouble with my library app in javaFX/SQL

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, phpmyadmin

i have a little problem with my LibraryApp, so my console show me that error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgFcv.png)
in PHPmyAdmin i created a few table:

- [book table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdmoN.png)
- [user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0illc.png)

and i connected them in lend table:

- [lend table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dDbg.png)
- [connection book and user with lend table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxVIM.png)

but, when i want add new lend phpMYAdmin it's work perfectly...

And here is code which should add to app and to database new lend:

```
 @Override
public boolean addLend(int userId, int bookId, String returnDate) {
    try {

        PreparedStatement preparedStatementInsert = connector.getPreparedStatement(
                "INSERT INTO lend VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

        preparedStatementInsert.setInt(1, 0);
        preparedStatementInsert.setInt(2, userId);
        preparedStatementInsert.setInt(3, bookId);
        preparedStatementInsert.setString(4, returnDate);
        preparedStatementInsert.setTime(5, null);
        preparedStatementInsert.execute();
        preparedStatementInsert.close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}




private void tryAddLend() {
    int userId = (textCustomeridAddLend.getText().trim().length());
    int bookId = (textbookidAddLend.getText().trim().length());
    String returnDay = textReturnDayAddLend.getText();

    if (!checkAddLendData()) {
        return;
    }

    if (mainDao.addLend(userId, bookId, returnDay)) {

        Utils.createSimpleDialog("login", "", "added correctly");
    } else {
        Utils.createSimpleDialog("login", "", "error");
    }
    loadLends();
}
```

Comment: Your stack trace image link is almost non readable, but I did see the constraint violation error pretty clearly.  This sort of error usually means that you are adding a child record which points to a parent record in another table which does not exist.  I question that this query worked fine from PHP admin; I think it would fail there too.

Comment: The error is very clear in the stack trace (You should paste the trace and not an image), you are violating a foreign key constraint: lend_ibfk_1. The established user id is not found in your db.

Comment: Better show the SQL statements for creating the tables (as text) instead of posting screenshots of phpMyAdmin. Also better post the stacktrace as a code block instead of a screenshot...